# How change edit control's text?

Tags: c++, button, text, mfc

I have a button and text control in MFC dialog window, when I click on button, in edit control must be replaced for example `"hello world"`.
but if I write

```
edit="hello wordl"
```

it doesn't change, *how can I change?*

Answer (score 1):

First you should add a variable to edit.To do that right click on the edit and choose Add Variable... in `Add Member variable Wizard` change Category from `Control` to `Value` after that in the Variable name field type a name like `m_EditValue` then click finish.from now you can change the Edit Control simply by following code.

```
   void CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
        m_EditValue = L"Hello World";
        UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SetWindowText` method:

```
edit.SetWindowText( _T("Hello, World!") );
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a CEdit member variable of the dialog. Use 'Add Variable' in the dialog editor. If you name this variable `m_helloedit` then in your button click function

```
m_helloedit.SetWindowText(_T("hello world!"));
```